# Estimating variance based on parameters

Tags: regression, multiple-regression, variance, uncertainty, weights

I have a list of measurements $y_1,\ y_2,\ ...,\ y_n$ of quantity $Y$ and a list of parameters associated with each measurement $(A,\ B,\ ...)_j,\ j=1...n$. The distribution of $Y$ is symmetric, but has higher kurtosis than normal distribution.
 I have made plots of $y_i-y_0$, where $y_0$ is a reference value, vs some of the parameters (red lines enclose 95% of points):
[image]
As you can see, variance depends heavily on these two parameters. However, these parameters could also be interrelated. Dependence of deviations on other parameters is not as pronounced. 
I would like to select parameters that influence variance the most and to approximate the uncertainty (measure of spread/precision) of individual measurement as a function of these parameters: $\sigma_i=c_0+c_1A_i+c_2B_i+...$
How should I go about finding these coefficients? This looks like a linear regression, but I'm not sure how to implement it since $\sigma_i$ are unknown.

---

For context, this is a chemistry problem. The "measurement" involves  a computational model that is too complex to use standard error propagation formualas. I wish to predict a property of a chemical species based on reactions that it's involved in. I feed many reactions to the model and it produces $y$ along with some diagnostic values. The parameters that I refer to include properties of these reactions (for example, sum of stoichiometric coefficients as in the above figure) and these diagnostic values. I would like to know how these parameters affect the accuracy of my predicted value to know which reactions work better (are less spread out). I also want to give more weight to more accurate values when calculating the mean and standard deviation.

Comment: Although this situation is reminiscent of various exploratory graphics, your description is too abstract to permit any good answer IMHO.  Could you provide some context or a more concrete description of what these "parameters" represent, how they are estimated, and what you really need to accomplish?

Comment: You can use the gamlss function in the gamlss library of R to estimate such functions.

Comment: @AdamO, hmm, that's an interesting thought. But I don't see how I can apply this model here, since the data is not sequential in any way, it's just a list of values obtained with different initial parameters. I probably should have been more careful with the word "series", I'll edit it out.

Comment: @BigBendRegion, thank you, I'll take a look at it.

Comment: Have you just considered performing multivariable regression with $(y_i - y_0)^2$ as a response?